# Trigger a function at a specific transition value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to trigger a function at a specific `transitionY` Value.

I found this:

```
document.getElementById("main").addEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", myFunction);

document.getElementById("main").addEventListener("transitionend", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    alert('huuh');
}
```

But it's only a trigger after a transition End. When I scroll down on my Page, a div box change the style value by (transform: translateY(-100%)).

I tried:

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('scroll-container').style.transform == "translateY(-100%)")
.......
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Have you tried using a css animation function? There you can at least specify what happens a 0%, 50%, 100%, etc... Might have some luck with that.

Comment: @mwilson how?? :) greetings

Comment: I hate mentioning links to w3fools, but this one seems to be good enough to demonstrate how to work with them: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery's $.animate function](https://api.jquery.com/animate/). Using *progress* attribute, you will be getting current status of the animation. e.g.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var transitionPointReached = false;
  $('#some-id').animate({
    opacity: 0.1
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
    progress: function(animation, progress, remaining){
      console.log('progress called', progress, remaining);
      if(!transitionPointReached && progress >= 0.7) {
        transitionPointReached = true;
        // call the required callback once.
      }
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
#some-id {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="some-id"></div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

or is it possible to trigger a function if the page reaches a new section? Like #0 (`<a id="button" href="#0"></a>` ) and went to  #1 ?

greetings

Here u can see what i mean :
http://salon-lifestyle.de.w0192ceb.kasserver.com/#0

Answer (score 0):

> or is it possible to trigger a function if the page reaches a new
>   section? Like #0 ( ) and went to #1 ?

The [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) API was designed for such usecases, it allows to triggers callback when the viewport reaches/crosses/has reached a set of children.

Regarding your transition question, you can do something like this but I would not recommend using it. You can fetch the exact value of the `transition` property using [element.cssText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/cssText)

```js
const dummyDiv = document.getElementById('dummy')

// Assuming the transition is linear and lasts 2secs, 
// mid-transiton happens after 1000ms
dummyDiv.addEventListener('transitionstart', () => {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    dummyDiv.innerHTML = 'mid transition'
  }, 1000)
})
dummyDiv.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
  dummyDiv.innerHTML = 'end transition'
})
```

```css
#dummy{
padding: 50px 100px;
font-size: 35px;
background: #000;
color: #FFF;
transition: 2s linear;
}

#dummy:hover{
background:red
}
```

```html
<div id="dummy">Hover me</div>
```